# Save tree view json to file using jq library

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I have like this json data in my case:

```
sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $LOGIN /bin/bash -s << EOT

echo "Saving to file.."

USER_DATA="{\"id\":"$USER_ID",\"sha\":"$USER_SHA"}"
echo "{\"id\":"$PRODUCT_ID",\"user\":"$USER_DATA"}" | jq -re > ~/user.json

EOT
```

When I tried save this json to file get error with message:

> parse error: Unmatched '}' at line 1, column 21

How I can save correctly my json data to file?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you need to escape a bunch more of the quotes. You're doing a whole lot of difficult/troublesome things, here: bash here docs, embedded json within other json and the quoting therein, and then doing it all via SSH. My suggestion: get each piece working as simply as possible and then build it up piece by piece. You may need to revert to a shell script rather than ssh with a here doc.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `jq` to create your json. Try something like this :

```
sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $LOGIN /bin/bash -s << EOT

echo "Saving to file.."

jq --arg id "$PRODUCT_ID" -n '{$id}' | \
jq --arg id "$USER_ID" \
   --arg sha "$USER_SHA" \
   --arg user "user" \
   '.[$user]={$id, $sha}' > ~/user.json

EOT
```

---

**Explanations:**

- `--arg id "$PRODUCT_ID"` : create a variable for jq, called `id` which contains the value taken from `$PRODUCT_ID`
- `-n '{$id}'` : create a new json template

  - This will take the variable name as well as its value
  - Here, this creates the json `{id : $id}`
- `jq ... | jq ...` : we pass the output of the 1st `jq` command as the input of the 2nd command
- `'.[$user]={$id, $sha}'` : we add new elements to the input

  - `.[$user]` : the element name from the `$user` variable
  - `{$id, $sha}` : will create an object from the variables, i.e. `{id : $id, sha : $sha}`
  - the whole command creates the element : `user : {id : $id, sha : $sha}`

Comment: Can you please explain what this is doing? I've never used jq to create JSON, but I love the idea.

Comment: @AndyLester I've expanded my answer. Please tell me if some points are unclear

Comment: The two invocations of jq can easily be combined, enhancing both efficiency and simplicity.

Comment: @peak I split them on purpose : there are 2 variables named `id`